# Editable table in material design

Tags: gui-design, input-fields, material-design, data-tables, inline-edit

we're designing a web application in material design and we have an editable table there - something like this:

[image: Copied from material design specification]

Any suggestion on how to indicate the editable fields, if not all columns are editable? Let's say that in this example Protein and Comments would be editable - how should we visualize this?

I found this suggestion in Material design specification, but what if more than one column in a row is editable? The table would become cluttered with icons if we place them into each editable cell.

[image: Material design - editable table]

Would it be better to allow editing only for the whole row?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you like to keep the table clean, show only the edit icon on the hovered cell:
You can specify which cells are editable by showing the icon or not.
[image: [enter image description here]
Keep text selectable:
[image]
And add a click handler on the edit icon itself:
[image]

I would recommend not using inline editing, since column widths can be small and not easy to edit. Use a pop-up/-over or modal or something like this:

[image]

Comment: [The spec page](https://material.io/guidelines/components/data-tables.html#data-tables-structure) shows diagrams of how to do "small" or "large" popover edit dialogs.

Comment: I'm surprised this is the best vote... Not that great of a solution and very inefficient.

Comment: @insidesin It would be much better to point out why do you think it is not a great solution. Even better if you provide what's a better solution would be and why.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative could be inline editing on hover. Showing just the editable fields.[image]

Comment: I think showing the inputs on hover is cleaner and more elegant than showing an icon for each field. The material style for the fields would be nice, but this was my idea too.

Comment: It is cleaner yes but more importantly it is more efficient as users can identify editable fields at a glance, without the need to hover each field to find out if it is editable or not.

Answer (score 3):

The material design suggestion seems okay.
One edit icon per row which makes every field in that row editable.
You could add "Edit row" to make it more clear what will happen.

[image: For Example]

Comment: But what if not all columns are editable? How do you distinguish editable vs. non-editable fields if material design fields have no outline?

Comment: This is the best method I see here. One edit icon in the same place every time, but content is editable if conditions are met. This needs good reasoning on why fields aren't editable though... that's the next problem.

Comment: @insidesin you can disable that text field for editing.

Comment: Yeah. So you need good reasoning on why those are disabled.

Comment: I want similar, will you provide me the stackblitz link, I m integrating angular mat table

Answer (score 3):

While tables in Material Design usually do not have any kind of outlines, in your case a good idea would be to use editable text field UIs in the places where you wish to indicate that fields are possible to modify. Below are two images, the first one showing a field without text inside (and with a placeholder), and the second one with text entered. **To make everything more legible, I would recommend removing the upper label in the filled in text field (see image two), since the label is already present at the top of the table (so the filled in field looks just like the empty one but with more visible black text to differentiate the other states).**

[image]

[image]